# bootstrap collapse all but one and one at the time

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've spent hours trying to find solution to this, but i failed... so I'm asking for help.

in jsfidlle i added a picture at the bottom, just to show how it is supposed to look like.

when you click on 'title', a new content opens collapsing the other two. in the meantime, one must stay active even if you double click it to close.

this is what i've done so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/u7L65ofn/2/

ps: i commented two sections so that they don't get in the way.

does anyone knows how to fix this??

```
<div class='ribon container' id='ribon_1'>
<div class="row bg-gray">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a id="rb-coll-1" class="txt-col-black" href="#rib-collapse-1"><h4><strong>Komentari</strong></h4></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a id="rb-coll-2" class="txt-col-black" href="#rib-collapse-2"><h4><strong>Najcitanije</strong></h4></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a id="rb-coll-3" class="txt-col-black" href="#rib-colapse-3"><h4><strong>Najnovije</strong></h4></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="rib-collapse-1" class="row bg-home txt-col-white rib-collapse col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <p>Mauris porta ipsum velit, et dignissim turpis lacinia ut. Vivamus ut nisi eu libero dapibus ornare. Mauris porta ipsum velit, et dignissim turpis lacinia ut. Vivamus ut nisi eu libero dapibus ornare.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <p>Mauris porta ipsum velit, et dignissim turpis lacinia ut. Vivamus ut nisi eu libero dapibus ornare. Mauris porta ipsum velit, et dignissim turpis lacinia ut. Vivamus ut nisi eu libero dapibus ornare.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <p>Mauris porta ipsum velit, et dignissim turpis lacinia ut. Vivamus ut nisi eu libero dapibus ornare. Mauris porta ipsum velit, et dignissim turpis lacinia ut. Vivamus ut nisi eu libero dapibus ornare.</p>
        </div>
</div>
<div id="rib-collapse-2" class="row bg-home txt-col-white rib-collapse col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <p>Mauris porta ipsum velit, et dignissim turpis lacinia ut. Vivamus ut nisi eu libero dapibus ornare.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <p>Mauris porta ipsum velit, et dignissim turpis lacinia ut. Vivamus ut nisi eu libero dapibus ornare.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <p>Mauris porta ipsum velit, et dignissim turpis lacinia ut. Vivamus ut nisi eu libero dapibus ornare.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="rib-collapse-3" class="row bg-home txt-col-white rib-collapse col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <p>Mauris porta ipsum velit, et dignissim turpis lacinia ut. Vivamus ut nisi eu libero dapibus ornare.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <p>Mauris porta ipsum velit, et dignissim turpis lacinia ut. Vivamus ut nisi eu libero dapibus ornare.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <p>Mauris porta ipsum velit, et dignissim turpis lacinia ut. Vivamus ut nisi eu libero dapibus ornare.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `Accordion` provided by Bootstrap itself instead of writng new css and js for the collapsible items?

Comment: I've been searching for a solution (though, i'm new to bootstrap). one open at all time, only one opens at the time. accordion doesn't solve this.